# Serving HTML from Flask, can't find image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm creating a Flask app frontend, my `index.html` can't find the images and files referenced in the code.

I've tried moving to the same folder but with no success.

Server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return open('html/index.html').read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True)
```

HTML lines:

```html
<img src="shards-logo-white.svg" alt="Example Navbar 1" class="mr-2" height="30">

<script src="js/shards.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo.min.js"></script>
```

Server debug output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 12:19:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 12:19:29] "GET /shards-logo-white.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 12:19:29] "GET /html/js/shards.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 12:19:29] "GET /html/js/demo.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

- The image `shards-logo-white.svg` is in the same folder.
- The js scripts are with the subdirectory `html` -> `js` -> *FILES*.

Answer (score 1):

No, Flask does not serve arbitrary files from the filesystem. Move any static files like those into the `static` subdirectory, then reference them via that path; you can use the full path of nested directoriess within the `static` path:

```html
<img src="/static/shards-logo-white.svg" alt="Example Navbar 1" class="mr-2" height="30">

<script src="/static/html/js/shards.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/html/js/demo.min.js"></script>
```

You *could* serve your HTML [rendered from a template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates), at which point you can use `{{ url_for('static', filename="shards-logo-white.svg") }}` and `{{ url_for('static', filename="html/js/shards.min.js") }}`, etc. to have Flask generate valid URLs for those paths.

See the [*Static Files* section of the quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files), as well as the [*Static Files* chapter of the tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/).

If you are not using a template then may as well serve your `html/index.html` file as a static file too. As it stands you are not rendering it as a template nor are you making any other runtime changes to the file contents.

Even if you do sometimes need to conditionally serve a file from disk, rather than read it all into memory I'd use the [`flask.send_file()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file) to make sure the file is served efficiently and with a reasonable content-type header:

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return send_file('html/index.html')
```

Relative paths are resolved against [`Flask.root_path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.root_path). You probably also want to consider [`flask.send_from_directory()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory), which will ensure that user-input for a filename can't be abused to serve arbitrary files outside of a designated directory.

Comment: Thank you, is is working.
Should I render the html as a template or there is no problem serving it this way?

Comment: @Milteven: only render your HTML as a template if you actually have something to render dynamically. Rather than use `open(...).read()`, you can use [`Flask.send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file) to have Flask put a proper response around it and stream it out rather than read it all into memory first.